# Performing addition in QGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: raster-calculator, qgis-2.6

I am using QGIS 2.6 on Windows 7.

I have generated two rasters from vector layers. They cover the same extent and have the same projection (Irish Transverse Mercator) and cell size (5m x 5m). I have 'reclassified grid values' to ensure that both rasters now have values of only 0 or 10. I have been attempting to add the rasters together in the raster calculator ("NPWS@1"+"CH_Extract@1") and I am expecting to see values of 0, 10 or 20 (where there is overlap between the two original vector datasets). Instead I get an output layer with values of 0 or 9.989990. I have tried every permutation I can think of to fix this and am having no joy.

Comment: Have you set the output extent and resolution appropriately?

Comment: I believe so, I have used the same projection, extent and resolution when I have saved the final rasters as a GTiffs, which I have then added to QGIS for the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your individual rasters are not aligned. So, when they are added the result is a weighted average for the values in the overlaping area. To solve this you have to use a merged vector layer whose extension must be used for producing individual raster. I used this procedure for testing it:

1) I created two vector layers (both with the same value field = 10) where they are overlaped in some area:

[image]

2) I merged them and I wrote down its extension:

[image]

3) Using the extension to rasterize (by value field = 10) the first vector layer:

[image]

4) First vector layer rasterized:

[image]

5) Second vector layer rasterized:

[image]

6) sum_raster obtained by using raster calculator. You can observe that the sum is 20 in overlaped areas (Value Tool plugin). The values: 0 (black area), 10 (gray area), 20 (white area).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@xunilk pointed me towards the 'Value Tool' plugin which has allowed me to track down where things were going wrong. I had posted a previous query to stackexchange regarding the fact that when I was creating rasters the values being displayed did not reflect what I was ascribing. I noted the same with you screen captures above. When a value of 10 has been ascribe QGIS displays the raster as having values from 0 to 9.99. When I added two rasters together I got max values of 19.98. When I added three I was still getting max values of 19.98 yet when I passed the Value Tool over the raster it was telling me that there were areas of value 0, 10, 20 and **30**, as indicated in the image below.

[image: Scree capture of QGIS showing raster with 'Max' value indicated as 19.98 but with actual values of up to 30 in the 'Value Tool' window]

Going into the properties dialogue and 'Stretch(ing) to MinMax' does not affect this.

[image: Screen capture of QGIS showing 'Properties' dialogue 'Style' tab with raster max / min values]

Even though the raster meta data clearly states that for Band 1 the Statistics_Maximum is 30.

[image: Raster meta data showing Statistics_Maximum for raster band 1]

With this knowledge I have overridden the the 'Max' value for 'Band Rendering' and everything now looks good.

[image: Screen capture of QGIS with raster max value overridden to display actual max of 30]

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate if you mark the question as answered. Thanks!